# Multiple COUNTIFS

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I have a bunch of columns on my 'Inventory' sheet:

- Column A has purchase dates.
- Column F has types of multipacks that were purchased that day.
- Column H has single items purchased.

The below formula *should* either return '0' if none of the items appear for 27/11/2019 OR it should return the total number of instances of the specified items and multipacks (redbox, nc-pack, multiA, Combo, Mix10) for 27/11/2019.

For example, if in column A '27/11/2019' appears in 7 rows, and in two of the adjacent rows in column F 'Combo' appears and in one of the adjacent rows in column H 'redbox' appears, then the below formula should return '3'. But it doesn't.

What am I missing? I've found a few similar COUNTIFS answers on here, but none that specifically match what I'm trying to do.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(COUNTIFS('Inventory'!A:A,"27/11/2019",'Inventory'!H:H,{"*redbox*","*nc-pack*"}) + COUNTIFS('Inventory'!A:A,"27/11/2019",'Inventory'!F:F,{"*multiA*","*Combo*","*Mix10*"})),0)
```

Without the IFERROR, it returns #N/A, so it's not recognising these terms, even though they are in the referenced cells.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently it will work with a comma instead of the + sign:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(COUNTIFS('Inventory'!A:A,"27/11/2019",'Inventory'!H:H,{"*redbox*","*nc-pack*"}),COUNTIFS('Inventory'!A:A,"27/11/2019",'Inventory'!F:F,{"*multiA*","*Combo*","*Mix10*"})),0)
```